# Como carregar uma imagem respeitando / vinculando com o retorno de uma variável no Json

Tags: json, imagem

Bom dia amigos....

Não sei se vou conseguir me fazer entender, mas necessito carregar uma imagem vinculado ao tipo de retorno que venha a receber do Json.

Exemplo:

Sinal Vermelho, Amarelo e Verdade

```
echo 'SINAL' .$data["CreditData"][0]["SINAL"].'</td>';
```

Digamos que retorne vermelho.... em vez de aparecer escrito, queria carregar uma imagem vermelho.... vermelho.png

Pergunto como posso fazer isso?

```html
<img src='' id="icone" width="60px">
<br/>

<script>
$(document).ready(function(){
 $('#icone').attr('src','https://meusite.com.br/icons/' + data[0].sinal + '.png');
 });
});
</script>
```

Aguem tem alguma ideia para me ajudar?

Abraços

Comment: O `script` é na mesma página PHP ou é um `.js` externo?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Marcos, tudo bem?

Você pode deixar uma **div** ou qualquer outra tag vazia no local onde você quer que apareça a imagem. Depois disso, no resultado da sua solicitação do **JSON**, você pode criar um element **img** com javascript e pendura-lo na sua **div** vazia.

Por exemplo:

```
<div id="image"></div>

<script>
var img = document.createElement("IMG");
img.src = "img/exemplo.png";
document.getElementById('image').appendChild(img);
</script>
```

Claro que você deverá colocar as condições de acordo com seu retorno, porém essa lógica é da forma que você gostaria. Você pode utilizar o **AJAX** para capturar esse arquivo **JSON**.

***EDIT:**
Eu preferia que você utilizasse uma chamada "**AJAX**" para capturar o **JSON** direto no **JAVASCRIPT**, sem utilizar o **PHP**.
Porém podemos resolver mais rapidamente esse problema.

Você pode adicionar esse valor do **PHP** dentro de um **input** oculto, capturar o valor do mesmo pelo **javascript** e fazer o processo, por exemplo:

```
<input value="<?php $data["CreditData"][0]["SINAL"] ?>" id="cor" type="hidden"></input>

<div id="image"></div>

<script>
var cor = document.getElementById('cor').value;
var img = document.createElement("IMG");

if(cor === "red")
   img.src = "img/vermelho.png";
else if(cor === "green")
   img.src = "img/verde.png";


document.getElementById('image').appendChild(img);
</script>
```

Creio que isso resolverá seu problema, porém deixarei um link para você aprender como funciona a requisição **AJAX**:
https://www.devmedia.com.br/ajax-com-jquery-trabalhando-com-requisicoes-assincronas/37141

Comment: Luis, obrigado pelo retorno...

Mas a questão que img/exemplo.png vai variar... podendo ser vermelho.png ou verde.pnj ou até amarelo.png.... tudo depende do que retornar da consulta ao Json. Dai minha duvida como carregar a imagem que corresponda com o que retornar da consulta do Json

Comment: Você poderia me dizer qual é o retorno do JSON?
Provavelmente você terá uma informação que te dirá qual cor você quer, com base nisso, você coloca condições "if... else" para dizer qual a cor. Você pode alterar apenas o img.src = "linkdaimg.png" dentro dos "if" colocando o caminho que você precisa dependendo da condição

Comment: Luis, ele retornar assim echo 'SINAL' .$data["CreditData"][0]["SINAL"].

O retorno do SINAL pode ser: red ou green dai conforme o aquel aparecer eu gostaria que chamasse ... red.png ou green.png... poderia fazer um exemplo para mim?

Comment: Marcos, fiz uma edição na minha resposta, creio que a mesma poderá lhe ajudar!

Comment: Luis é bem isso ai ... só não estou conseguindo conexão com o Json... mas to tentando aqui